# When running yarn, yarn.lock file is generated with private token from bash

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, gem-fury

I'm using Gem Fury for some of our private packages. I set the yarn registry to use their proxy for public and our private node modules:

```
yarn config set registry "https://npm-proxy.fury.io/$GEMFURY_TOKEN/username"
```

`GEMFURY_TOKEN` is set in `.bash`. `yarn config get registry` produces:

```
https://npm-proxy.fury.io/$(GEMFURY_TOKEN)/username
```

When we run `yarn`, the `yarn.lock` file will generate this:

```
private-module@0.1.0:
  version "0.1.0"
  resolved "https://npm.fury.io/username/private-module/-/0.1.0.tgz?auth=<GEMFURY TOKEN>"
  dependencies:
    ember-cli-babel "^5.1.6"

private-module-2@0.1.4:
  version "0.1.4"
  resolved "https://npm.fury.io/username/private-module-2/-/0.1.4.tgz?auth=<GEMFURY TOKEN>"
  dependencies:
    ember-cli-babel "^5.1.6"
    ember-inflector "^1.9.6"
```

I don't want private tokens in the git repository. Is there a way I can exclude the token from being added to the `yarn.lock` file on generation?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with a private NPM feed hosted on MyGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set up `npm` as described in [Gem Fury documentation](https://gemfury.com/help/private-yarn/).
The crucial parts are setting `always-auth` to `true` and using `npm login`

If this doesn't help then you can use `Git` [pre-commit hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that will remove credentials from `yarn.lock` when changes are commited to `Git` repository.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that might be the only practical option so far. What I don't like about it is that it requires so much discipline from the developer (adding the hook every time you create a new repo that uses private packages), and it's rather low level and not generic: you might have to customise the hook for a specific pattern depending on your private registry. And finally, what if you're using something else than Git? I'll keep the bounty running for now, but you just might win it.

Comment: BTW have you tried to set up `yarn` as described here; https://gemfury.com/help/private-yarn/, does it still saves credentials in `yarn.lock` then?

Comment: Also here is a  feature request exactly on your issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5024, but `yarn` maintainers refused to implement it

Comment: We managed to solve the problem by using a similar setup as the one described in the Gem Fury documentation you mentioned (we are using MyGet). If you would kindly update your answer to reflect this,  I think this would make a great canonical answer. The crucial parts are setting `always-auth` to `true` and using `npm login`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem recently, but the Gemfury documentation doesn't really make it obvious. If you need to pull or push in your CI build then I don't think you should use `npm login` as that will modify your home `.npmrc`, which isn't very helpful. We found that all you need to do is change your project's `.npmrc` to use the shared organization account. This way you can have your project's `.npmrc` version controlled so your developers and your CI server can read from the same registry URL while keeping your lock file token-free:

```
@MY_ORG:registry=https://npm-proxy.fury.io/MY_ORG/
always-auth=true
//npm-proxy.fury.io/MY_ORG/:_authToken=${GEMFURY_TOKEN}
```